# how to put anonymous json as class member and convert all to json in c#

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

I'm having a well-defined class for sending as JSON body in an HTTP request.

```
public class EventData
{
    public string deviceJobId { get; set; }
    public int eventID { get; set; }
    public long time_ms { get; set; }
    /// similar fields
}
```

Now I have to add one more field called `HealthInfo`. The value of this new `HealthInfo` is a nested JSON read from some file.
The fields of this JSON file change from time to time, and there is no guarantee that some fields will always be present.

I don't want to read/modify any value of that and just need to publish this `EventData` as a json as part of an HTTP request.

Then how to add `HealthInfo` correctly?

I tried to put `HealthInfo` as string and object is getting double serialized.

Comment: You have to show the code you use to create an HTTP body

Comment: If `HealthInfo` is an unstructured set of key/value pairs, maybe a `Dictionary<string, string>`?

Answer (score 2):

you have to convert to JObject before you add new json string

```
JObject jo = JObject.FromObject(eventData);

jo["HealthInfo"] = jsonStringHealthInfo;

//or it could be (your question needs some details)
jo["HealthInfo"]=JObject.Parse(jsonStringHealthInfo);

StringContent   content = new StringContent(jo.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

var response = await client.PostAsync(api, content))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know all of the possible properties inside HealthInfo then you can create new class `HealthInfo` with nullable properties.

```
public class HealthInfo
{
    public string? SomeData { get; set; }
    public int? SomeOtherData { get; set; }
}
```

and then add nullable HealthInfo in your main class:

```
public class EventData
{
    public string deviceJobId { get; set; }
    public int eventID { get; set; }
    public long time_ms { get; set; }
    public HealthInfo? HealthInfo { get; set; }
    /// similar fields
}
```

However if you're not sure what kind of data you're gonna get and want to avoid double serialization, just pass HealthInfo as object:

```cs
public class EventData
{
    public string deviceJobId { get; set; }
    public int eventID { get; set; }
    public long time_ms { get; set; }
    public object? HealthInfo { get; set; }
    /// similar fields
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use of C# reflection. (TypeBuilder.DefineProperty Method)
In fact you must add prop to the class in run time.

see full information at

[https://learn.microsoft.com/](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.emit.typebuilder.defineproperty?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-7.0#System_Reflection_Emit_TypeBuilder_DefineProperty_System_String_System_Reflection_PropertyAttributes_System_Type_System_Type___)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).